# JUnit version 3.8 or later expected on android studio 4.1

Tags: android, junit, junit4, android-studio-4.1

I have updated the Android studio to 4.1 and when I run JUnit I get below eorror

```
 !!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:14)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:49)
```

Below is my configuration

```
JUnit Version: 4.12

Mockito Version: 3.5.11

PowerMockito Version: 2.0.7

Espresso Version: 3.3.0

Gradle Plugin version: 4.0.2 and 4.1.0

Gradle Version: 6.1.1 and 6.5
```

When I donwngradle to 4.0.2 it works fine

Please tell me what I am missing..

Comment: even am getting the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue when I upgrade to AS 4.1

I resolved this by removing the following from the `build.gradle (app)` file

```
useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
```

All tests run to completion

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue yesterday after updating my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ,i was installed android studio from sanp store . finally managed to solve issue temporary , if you are in linux you have to find installed directory of android studio and inside bin directory , run studio.sh with sudo , it seems that it is a permission issue

```
sudo ./android-studioInstalledDirectory/bin/studio.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue when I upgrade Android Studio to 4.1.  Instead of removing the `useLibrary` line, I removed the `testImplementation` line I had before upgrading that brought in a version of JUnit explicitly.